# What are Java Classpath and Path?

Tags: java, class, classpath

I have been googling around, trying to understand what the Java Classpath and Path are. However, I am stil not quite sure if I have understood it or not. If feel that this topic is one of those grey areas.

Can someone explain me what those are? I mean, where do I find and set them (where is the actual text file on Mac/Windows)? Is there only one instance of each one? If so, how do I set the path for multiple classes?

As you might have notices, I am totally confused right now after reading so many different tutorials... So now I really would like to have a straight forward explanation.

Please help me, I just trying to learn :)
Thank you all

Comment: [This is the first result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) when I typed *Java Classpath and Path* on google.

Comment: I know!!! I have read it but I still don't get it. Call me stupid but that wont help me a lot.

Comment: It's so not a gray area: it's well-defined and documented. Path = where executables are found. Classpath = where java classes are found.

Comment: @DaveNewton But even you dont say what it actually is. What are those path and classpath things?? Say if I wanted to look at them. What would I search for? A textfile, a folder???

Comment: They are environment variables. This is basic operating system literacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path is just a folder location. *The* path is where your OS will look for programs by default. If `java`, `javac`, `javap`, etc, etc, are in your path then you can just type their names without the entire folder location.

Your *classpath* is similar. It is a set of folders that contain .class files describing classes(hence the name) and .jar files, which are basically files that *contain* .class files. All code that you're running is either out of the classpath, generated, or out of the java libaries(also part of the classpath, techncically).

With each run of a java program you can specify a classpath by parameters passed to the `java` executable. It also grabs classes out of "extension folders,", special folders Java keeps around to act as a system classpath, and finally, the "bootstrap classes", which are a set of important classes almost any Java program needs to run.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. But if the classpath is a set of folders with .class files, does that mean that on my computer there is just one classpath that contains the location of all .class files on my machine??

Comment: @user2426316 Refer to edits. Also hit the checkmark next to the post that helped you the most.

Comment: Thank you, I really apprecicate your help. However I still dont get it... Can you point me to some **beginner** tutorial just on java classpath, path and how to set them??

Comment: @user2426316 The tutorial you linked should be good. Your IDE will also take care of most of it, letting you concentrate more on the code and algorithms than the classpath and configuration. If you use Eclipse, the defaults should be fine unless you're using a complex set of libraries.,

Comment: One last question: I tried to run an eclipse project but I get the exception `ClassNotFoundException`. Obviously there is a wrong path in my class path. How can I fix that in eclipse?

Comment: It may not necessarily be a classpath error. You could simply be missing an import or have misspelled a class name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mean of path is location of file system. if you want to access any file then you have to manually needs to go there location.
just example: d:\text1.txt then needs to go that d:\ location. same way java program have command like

```
javac -for compile
java  - for run 


.
.
.
etc.
```

that inside **java-jdk\bin** folder
so if you don't set into classpath. then you can execute java program like

```
run->cmd

c:\jdk1.6\bin> javac test.java
```

so without going explicit way you can set it into classpath, and direct execute java program from anywhere.

You can set java path as environment variable of computer.

Comment: You can do it using `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/some.jar:/path/to/some/other.jar`

Answer (score 0):

The PATH is basically where your JDK is installed; this is essentially what your IDE will look for when trying to compile or create Javadoc or such; it's basically just the location of a folder on your hard drive, set as a Windows (or other OS) environment variable to make it easier to use.

The CLASSPATH is a property that tells the compiler where to look for *classes*. Basically if you download a library or such from somewhere, you need to add it to the CLASSPATH for the compiler to use it. Usually you can do this in your IDE, however, you should not need to directly access the CLASSPATH variable.

By the way, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) is pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1)java Path: it is location of binary executable files
example :javac , java
this file are used for compile and run

2)class Path: it is location of .class file(file create after compile your source code .java file)