# ChromeDriver works from IDE, but not from a jar

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So, when I try to use a chromedriver from a jar file, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver
    at SelJarTest.main(SelJarTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

However, when I run the program from an IDE (IntelliJ CE), it works just fine.

Here's my Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And my code:

```
public class SelJarTest
{
    private static final String WEB_DRIVER_PROP = "webdriver.chrome.driver");
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          String oldProp = System.getProp(WEB_D_PROP);
          System.setProp(WEB_DRIVER_PROP, "chromedriver" + File.seperator + "chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeDriver cd = new ChromeDriver();

          System.out.println("Enter stuff: ");
          int userin;
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          while((userin = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) < 9)
          {
              if(userin %2 == 0)
                  cd.navigate().to("https://www.youtube.com");
          }

          scan.close();
          cd.close();
          System.clearProp(WEB_DRIVER_PROP);

          if(oldProp != null)
             System.setProp(WEB_DRIVER_PROP, oldProp);
          System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

For a little more clarity, the chromedriver.exe is in a folder called chromedriver, which is in the same directory as the jar:

```
DIR> chromedriver/chromedriver.exe
     SelJarTest.jar
```

Nothing I've found online seems to help resolve this. What have found that was similar to the error, was a bunch of "Oh, you need such and such dependency, or such and such file." I am wanting to avoid the use of environment variables, so that my co-workers might be able to run the program if I put the file on a server for them to use.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you running from the jar file? Are you missing the classpath? I you don't use maven to run the test (and it's correctly configured), for example the way you defined your dependencies are being added only to the "compile" phase thus this is the default dependencies scope https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: I was just executing the jar from CMD: java -jar SelJarTest.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Java Classpath and Path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409714/what-are-java-classpath-and-path)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to my plight. I wasn't creating the jar file with everything I needed.

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE, and I should have been creating the Jar artifact from modules with dependencies.
Project Structure > Artfacts > Add > JAR > from modules with dependencies...

My dependencies ended up being:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.26.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the selenium dependencies the following

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

And use the following to run the tests

> mvn test

Comment: The build fails:[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SeleniumJarTest: Could not resolve dependencies for project SeleniumJarTest:SeleniumJarTest:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver:selenium-java:jar:3.0.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Think you need to replace the Chrome driver dependency with the one in: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.seleniumhq.selenium%7Cselenium-chrome-driver%7C3.0.1%7Cjar